# Desired checkbox in not being activated

Tags: html, css

When I click on second checkbox, first check box is activated.

But When I click on the First checkbox, every thing works fine.

**Please click on the second checkbox and see What happening.**

***I have 1000's of check boxes!*** **and change id is not a good way!**

If you need more details, comment on the question!

Here is the code please have a look:

```css
.checkboxFour{
 width: 14px;
 height: 14px;
 background: #dddddd;
 margin: 0px 0px;
 border-radius: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -20px;
 margin-right: -18px;
}
.checkboxFour > input{visibility: hidden;/* position: absolute; *//* z-index:-1000; *//* overflow: hidden; *//* clip: rect(0 0 0 0); */height: 17px;width: 14px;margin: -2px;margin-right: -7px;padding:0;border:0;}
.checkboxFour label{
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 border-radius: 100px;
 transition: all .5s ease;
 cursor: pointer;
 top: 0px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 2px;
 z-index: 1;
 background: #ddd;
 margin-top: 2px;
 margin-right: 2px;
}
.checkboxFour input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
 background: #f83232;
}
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<br>
<td><div class="checkboxFour"><input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxFourInput" name=""><label for="checkboxFourInput"> </label> Important</div></td>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<td><div class="checkboxFour"><input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxFourInput" name=""><label for="checkboxFourInput"> </label> </div>Not Important</td>
```

ThankYou!

Comment: "and change id is not good way" —Yes, it is.

Comment: every element need unique id use dynamic id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens, because you have put same id-s to input, and both labels were referring to that id:

```css
.checkboxFour{
 width: 14px;
 height: 14px;
 background: #dddddd;
 margin: 0px 0px;
 border-radius: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -20px;
 margin-right: -18px;
}
.checkboxFour > input{visibility: hidden;/* position: absolute; *//* z-index:-1000; *//* overflow: hidden; *//* clip: rect(0 0 0 0); */height: 17px;width: 14px;margin: -2px;margin-right: -7px;padding:0;border:0;}
.checkboxFour label{
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 border-radius: 100px;
 transition: all .5s ease;
 cursor: pointer;
 top: 0px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 2px;
 z-index: 1;
 background: #ddd;
 margin-top: 2px;
 margin-right: 2px;
}
.checkboxFour input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
 background: #f83232;
}
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<br>
<td><div class="checkboxFour"><input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxFourInput" name=""><label for="checkboxFourInput"> </label> Important</div></td>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<td><div class="checkboxFour"><input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxFourInput2" name=""><label for="checkboxFourInput2"> </label> </div>Not Important</td>
```

Comment: I need to another way! I have 1000 checkbox!

Comment: Each checkbox must have a specific id! @Alireza

Answer (score 0):

```css
.checkboxFour{
 width: 14px;
 height: 14px;
 background: #dddddd;
 margin: 0px 0px;
 border-radius: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -20px;
 margin-right: -18px;
}
.checkboxFour > input{visibility: hidden;/* position: absolute; *//* z-index:-1000; *//* overflow: hidden; *//* clip: rect(0 0 0 0); */height: 17px;width: 14px;margin: -2px;margin-right: -7px;padding:0;border:0;}
.checkboxFour label{
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 border-radius: 100px;
 transition: all .5s ease;
 cursor: pointer;
 top: 0px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 2px;
 z-index: 1;
 background: #ddd;
 margin-top: 2px;
 margin-right: 2px;
}
.checkboxFour input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
 background: #f83232;
}
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<br>
<td><div class="checkboxFour"><input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxFourInput" name=""><label for="checkboxFourInput"> </label> Important</div></td>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<td><div class="checkboxFour"><input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxFourInput_2" name=""><label for="checkboxFourInput_2"> </label> </div>Not Important</td>
```

change your `for` and `id` of your second label and div

Comment: I need to another way! I have 1000 check box!

Comment: then u dont know beetwen 'for' and 'id' is used for